# asp.net map route with parameter inside controller and view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I need to create a url scheme like this

```
friend/{userid}/wishlist
```

where friend is the controller, wishlist is the view, and userid is the id of hte friend whose wishlist you would like to see.

I have setup a route like this

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "FriendWishlist",
            "friend/{userid}/wishlist",
            new { controller = "WishList", action="FriendWishlist", userid = 123}
            );
```

when i try to browse to `/friend/123/wishlist` i get the following error

> A public action method '123' was not
>   found on controller
>   'GiffrWeb.Areas.Api.Controllers.FriendController'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes in MVC are evaluated in the order they are declared.  It sounds very much like you have declared your route **below** the default one:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "FriendWishlist",
    "friend/{userid}/wishlist",
    new { controller = "WishList", action="FriendWishlist", userid = 123}
);
```

So the MVC framework is trying to match your URL `/friend/123/wishlist` first to the default route.  Because it's all variables and everything has a default or is optional, it's guaranteed to match.  It doesn't check if the controllers and actions exist and take the relevant arguments.  You have a `FriendController` class - check.  `123` action - it goes bang.

Simplest fix - declare the route above the default one (ie just swap these two statements) and it should work OK.

I might just add that it seems a little weird to have a URL that starts with `/friend/` going to a WishList controller when you obviously have a Friend controller (your error message says so).

Finally, I can't recommend highly enough that if you introduce custom routing that you also test those routes thoroughly - as you have seen, the routing engine often might not do what you think it does.  I recommend either the route testing stuff in [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) or Brad Wilson's [blog post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/testing-routing-and-url-generation-in-aspnet-mvc.html).